# how to search list of numbers in different fields of different tables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a list of numbers, which I have loaded into a temporary table in the database. I need to find if those numbers are in two different tables and in different fields of those tables. For example...

## TemporaryTable

**field1** values(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,...n)

**Table1**
ID, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8

**Table2**
ID, n1, n2, n3, n4

The `ID` of `Table1` and `Table2` are the same.
The values on `field1` in `#TemporaryTable` can be in any field of any of the two tables.

In addition, the numbers in the temporary table are flat and in the fields of the other two tables they can have dashes `-`. This I have solved using `REPLACE (n1, '-', '')`

I just want to show the `ID` and the number. If it does not exist in either, I just do not show it.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

What is your ultimate motivation?  If you really are finding that you have to do this, maybe you want to reconsider your design.  But, just for fun:

First, let's actually create those tables:

```
create table #table1 ( 
    ID int identity(1,1), 
    n1 int, n2 int, n3 int, n4 int, 
    n5 int, n6 int, n7 int, n8 int
);

insert #table1 values 
    (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
    (5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12),
    (9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16);

create table #table2 ( 
    ID int identity(1,1), 
    n1 int, n2 int, n3 int, n4 int
);

insert #table2 values 
    (1,2,3,4),
    (3,4,5,6),
    (7,8,9,10);
```

Now, verticalize by means of unpivot, so that the values are all in one column:

```
declare @verticalized table (
    tbl int,
    id int,
    col char(2),
    val int
);

insert     @verticalized        
select     1 tbl, id, col, val
from       #table1
unpivot    (val for col in (n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6,n7,n8)) up

union all
select     2, id, col, val
from       #table2
unpivot    (val for col in (n1,n2,n3,n4)) up
```

Then do some aggregations to answer your questions.

```
select     val,
           tbls = count(distinct tbl), -- # of tables value is in
           cols = count(distinct col), -- # of columns value is in

           -- specific locations you can find the value
           locations = stuff((
               select   
               distinct ',T' + convert(char(1),tbl) + '.C' + col
               from     @verticalized sub
               where    sub.val = v.val
               for xml  path('')
           ),1,1,'')

from       @verticalized v
group by   val
```

You mention presence in 'field1', in particular.  You can probably work the code from there.